# Street, road, crescent, lane, drive, way and more

Tags: word-choice

The English language is rich in ways to define a motorway, but what about *square*; can you help me find other definitions of it, or square-like spaces?

Comment: Place? Platz? Piazza?

Comment: What kind of *"square"* are you interested in? Do you mean an intersection of two or three roads (e.g. [Inman Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inman_Square) in Cambridge, MA), or an actual square-shaped park-like area formed by four roads (e.g. [Farragut Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farragut_Square) in Washington, DC). Or something else?

Comment: Seems like a thesaurus would be the first stop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The USPS maintains a list of street suffixes and their abbreviations.

https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm

The shape of each of the listed items is not given nor seldom even implied. Some that suggest to me something other than a long thin via:

CENTER, COURT, COMMONS, FIELD, FLAT, KNOLL, PLAZA

Comment: The obvious QUADRANGLE seems to be missing from the list.

Comment: From the top, Bluffs can be any shape.  From the side, they tend to look rectangular.